# OMNeT++: Changes is .cc class definition do not apply in simulation

Tags: omnet++

I have built a very simple network (similar to TicToc example). My problem is that when I change the .cc file for one of the defined classes, the changes do not apply when I run the simulation. Specifically I have changed the string name of a message, but with no effects.

When I go back to the TicToc example and I perform a similar change in the .cc file, the change applies perfectly fine.

I have the feeling that the problem lies on building the make files, etc. Is there any way to build the project from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing the .exe file created in the source folder before each new simulation. Apparently, my computer is not able to automatically remove the current .exe file during simulation and I therefore have to do it manually.