# Changing .cc file doesn't affect the simulation

Tags: omnet++

I changed some .cc files in OMNeT++, but when I run the simulation I see that none of them are applied.

I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193778/omnet-changes-is-cc-class-definition-do-not-apply-in-simulation) that the problem might be solved removing the .exe (in the case of Windows). However, I'm using Ubuntu and I'm not sure about what to do...

Any ideas?

Comment: did you (re-)compile the code after making the changes?

Comment: yes, but it's still the same...

Comment: can you post the before and after version of the files that you have changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did `make makefiles` and `make` again and I could see the changes. Maybe it isn't the best way...but if I just clean the project some errors appear and I can't run it anymore unless I do what I said above.

Comment: you don't need to `clean` the project each time, you compile. Among others, `make makefiles` should be used when adding new header files...